# clang does not compile a simple c file

Tags: objective-c, c, cygwin, llvm, clang

I've just installed clang in to cygwin:
clang version 3.1 (trunk 151024)
TargetL i386-pc-cygwin
Thread model: posix

However when trying to compile a simple c file (only main), the error occured:

```
clang version 3.1 (trunk 151024)
Target: i386-pc-cygwin
Thread model: posix
 "/usr/local/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple i386-pc-cygwin -S -disable-free -main-file-name t.c -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu pentium4 -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -resource-dir /usr/local/bin/../lib/clang/3.1 -fmodule-cache-path /var/tmp/clang-module-cache -fno-dwarf-directory-asm -fdebug-compilation-dir /toolchain4 -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -mstackrealign -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fgnu-runtime -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-fragile-abi -fdiagnostics-show-option -o /cygdrive/c/Users/Br0ther/AppData/Local/Temp/t-zyOz8h.s -x c t.c
clang: error: unable to execute command: Program could not be executed
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Please submit a bug report to http://llvm.org/bugs/ and include command line arguments and all diagnostic information.
clang: error: unable to execute command: Program could not be executed
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).
```

Any body out there knows what causes the problem? I have no idea what is the meaning of the message:

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Program could not be executed
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

Your help is greatly appreciated
NK

Comment: Did you try to run `clang -v -c yoursource.c` as suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all suggestions.
However, the issue is fixed by [increasing the heap size](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-maxmem.html) of cygwin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If these two lines are worrying you:

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Program could not be executed
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal
    (use -v to see invocation)
```

then might I suggest you (as suggested in the error message) change your command to see the invocation line it uses:

```
"/usr/local/bin/clang" -v -cc1 -triple i386-pc-cygwin ...
```

Then you will know the name of the program and you can investigate why it's not on your path (for example).